# How to @POST nested sub-resources in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I've looked at the Jersey documentation but I'm still a bit lost as to how to write nested resources in Jersey.

I have a Person resource for which I want there to be to-do list sub-resource. So you could login as a person and go to this url for your lists: {personId}/Lists/{listId}

```
 @Path("person")
public class PersonRestService {
    private PersonDataService dataService = PersonDataService.getInstance();
    private ToDoListDataService listDataService = ToDoListDataService.getInstance();

    //Omitted code for the Person resource

    //Get a list by it's numerical ID number
    @GET
    @Path("{id}/Lists/{listId}")
    public ToDoList getListById(@PathParam("id")String id, @PathParam("listId")String listId)
    {
        return listDataService.getToDoListById(listId);   
    }

    //Post a new list to the {personId}/Lists URL
    @POST
    @Path("{personId}/Lists/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String createToDoList(@PathParam("personId")String personId, @PathParam("listId")String listId,ToDoList newList)
    {
        return listDataService.addToDoList(newList);
    }
```

Here's the ToDoListDataService:

```
 public class ToDoListDataService {

    private static  ToDoListDataService ourInstance = new ToDoListDataService();
    private  List<ToDoList> ToDoLists = new ArrayList<>();

    public static ToDoListDataService getInstance()
    {
    return ourInstance;
}

// Functions for ToDoList

    public String addToDoList(ToDoList toDoList)
    {
        String newListId = Integer.toString(ToDoLists.size() + 1);
        toDoList.setId(newListId);
        ToDoLists.add(toDoList);
        return newListId;
    }

    public List<ToDoList> getLists()
    {
        return ToDoLists;
    }

    public ToDoList getToDoListById(String id)
    {
        for (ToDoList list: ToDoLists)
        {
            if(list.getId().equals(id))
            {
                return list;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void deleteToDoListById(String id)
    {
        for (ToDoList list: ToDoLists)
        {
            if(list.getId().equals(id))
            {
                ToDoLists.remove(list);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

In the Client App I call this function:

```
 private static void postToDoList(WebTarget target, String personId, String title)
    {

        ToDoList list = ClientUtil.createNewList(title);

        // Set correct path for the person who wants to create this list
        target = target.path(String.valueOf(personId) + "/Lists/" + String.valueOf(list.getId()));
        Response response = target.request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).post(Entity.json(list));

        System.out.println(response);
    }
```

But when I try to create a list for a personId that's been created, I get a 404 not found error. These operations are pretty similar to how I created the person class, so I must be doing something wrong with how I'm structuring my sub-resource class.

I also get null returned to the url after calling postToDoList, but even if I hard code it to work with a correct ID I still get a 404 not found.

Apologies in advance if this is a simple error, this is my first time working with Jersey.

Comment: Keep in mind that the default behavior is for a new resource instance to be created for each request. With that in mind, check your logic to see if that would make any difference.